# Unable to resolve LNK2001 error despite method appearing in lib file and being included

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2001

I have a C++ project `GWRegistry` that is set up as `x64 DynamicLibrary Win32Proj`. It is attempting to call a public constant in another DLL that has been added as a `native` nuget package. The project that created the dll was also set up as `x64 DynamicLibrary Win32Proj`.

The call is to `AuthorizationManagerDbo::m_strGUIDString` (yeah...the naming convention of `m_str` prefix is horrible...old code...not my fault).

The linker is returning error

```
unresolved external symbol "public: static class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,class
ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const AuthorizationManagerDbo::m_strGUIDString"
(?m_strGUIDString@AuthorizationManagerDbo@@2V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitATL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@@B)
```

I have **confirmed** that the dll containing the constant is being linked in as seen in the following snippet

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe
... /LIBPATH:C:\dev\WS\Gateway\packages\DbProcsEngine.1.2.3\build\native\x64 ... 
DbProcsEngine.lib ...
/MANIFEST ... /MACHINE:X64 /DLL x64\Debug\GWRegistry.res
```

I have also **confirmed** that the constant exists in the `DbProcsEngine.lib` via `dumpbin.exe` as seen here

```
Version      : 0
Machine      : 8664 (x64)
TimeDateStamp: D2185CEF
SizeOfData   : 00000086
DLL name     : DbProcsEngine.dll
Symbol name  : ?m_strGUIDString@AuthorizationManagerDbo@@2V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitATL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@@B (public: static class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const AuthorizationManagerDbo::m_strGUIDString)
  Type         : data
  Name type    : name
  Hint         : 458
  Name         : ?m_strGUIDString@AuthorizationManagerDbo@@2V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitATL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@@B
```

And that the signatures, `ATL::ChTraits..`, `CString`, etc. match.

Here is the declaration of the variable in the `cpp` file

```
public:

    // typedef CAtlString CLVString;   (elsewhere in code)
    static const CLVString m_strGUIDString;
```

I did read one SO post that mentioned a mismatch between `CharacterSet` could cause an issue but have confirmed that both are `Unicode`.

I am out of ideas of where else to look.

Comment: How have you declared the variable (and it's class) in your code?

Comment: @john - I added the declaration as requested. Keep in mind that this was previously working code. We have just been reorganizing solutions and projects in dedicated repos and instead of direct dll references and cross-solution project references, we have been pushing things to native nuget packages.